# Is the standard definition of tensor product an effective way to introduce it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra, universal-property

I was taught the tensor product via its universal property: *the* only object that satisfies ... up to isomorphism. Later, I literally *discovered* one could actually write down the elements of (some) tensor products (I was asked to list the elements of the tensor product of two finite fields).
It happened in France, because in my (Italian) university, no one ever showed anything like that to me.

Now I was wandering: one may introduce the definition of cartesian product through universal property, in a similar manner (I'm thinking about [something like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068939/misunderstanding-in-the-universal-property-of-the-cartesian-product)).

However, wouldn't such definition be simply too difficult to understand as an undergraduate student (and depending on his level, even for a graduated one). Moreover, I would feel confident in saying that the real fulfillment of the need of knowledge for what a cartesian product is *must* come from the notion of "the set of all possible ordered pairs...", and only after it can be systematized in a culturally more advance way.
If so, shouldn't it be the same for the tensor product?
Is there a better way to approach this concept (and if so, why is it so often presented the formal/categorical way?), and where one should start?

Comment: I personally like hearing both approaches. I think that for a lot of undergrads, the first time they encounter this paradigm is with the real numbers. Some programs brush over the construction of the reals, choosing to focus more on the fact that the reals are a unique ordered field ... Others spend more time developing the properties of the reals from the constructions (Dedekind cut, Cauchy equivalence classes, etc). When I was first learning about the reals, the latter approach was much more meaningful for my understanding, but as time passed, the former was much more valuable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's a fair comparison, but we cannot underestimate the fact that our brain comes with an (almost perfect) built-in mental model of the real set, already perfected by practice in high school. That is not the case for a tensor product at all... So in most cases I think that the choice of the formal introduction for reals (say, in Calculus 1) does not have to be as clear and bright as possible. There will be time for it later. However, without any shade of intuition, tensor product is intimidating at least.

Comment: While the universal property is more important than the elementwise description, I strongly agree that no undergraduate should be expected to study tensor products without ever hearing about what their elements are, and I'm surprised to hear of such pedagogy.

Comment: While I prefer the universal property *definition*, you will need the construction for *existence*, so you probably cannot work with only one of the two aspects. (Same with the reals: It is easy to show that any two complete ordered fields are uniquely isomorphic - but you still want  existence; and working *only* with the constructions may lead to misconceptions a la "is "0.9999\ldots=1$ or not?")

Comment: The universal property on its own is a specification and not a definition: the universal property specifies what we require of $A \otimes B$, but it only becomes a definition when we prove that something meeting those requirements exists for any given $A$ and $B$, (or depending on your acceptance of the axiom of choice, when we can prove that exactly one thing meeting those requirements for any given $A$ and $B$ exists).

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my question (I saw that definition a bunch of years ago and i never dived into it). Indeed, they exhibited also the classical construction (quotient of the "monstruous" vector space...), but I'll have to admit it: I remeber it was by no means any more clarifying. As far as I can tell, that construction is mostly a logical issue, for stating that such moudule always exists according to set theory. I would venture that it kind of feels tautological, being built up do to exactly what he has to do, in some sense.

Comment: Responding to Kevin: I guess you studied in a good university. As far as I can tell, the majority of "average" universities only care ((on average) about formalism, with no effort devoted to conveying any idea or reasoning techique. I've always wondered if this affects their comprehension and research (I guess so). It's a topic I would love to talk about, but I have noone to do it, apart from some colleagues who share my point of view...

Comment: The "monstrous" definition isn't really that bad: it's just trying to avoid picking bases for $A$ and $B$. If you have bases for $A$ and $B$, then you get a nice economical basis for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You might enjoy the following quote from Riehl's book on category theory >> KAN: "You have explained how the tensor product can be defined in terms of the hom functor. Can the hom instead be defined in terms of the tensor product?" EILENBERG: "No, of course not. That’s absurd." In fact, Kan’s intuition was correct. [..]

Comment: @RodolfoAssereto tensor products in general are difficult to understand, K.Conrad has some [interesting notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/) on tensor products.

Comment: Thank you @piombino,I hope I'll get to read them in the next weeks. But in the end, of course those 100 pages cannot be equivalent to the half-a-page definition, so why would even someone present the topic in such a way since it's useless anyway?

Comment: @roddik because that half-a-page is far from useless, it is enough (and fundamental) for the theoretical purposes of a commutative algebra (or algebraic geometry) book. In some sense, you could compare it to knowing the Hilbert basis theorem vs. the whole Grobner bases theory. Often you don't even care what the tensor products actually are, you only care about their existence and properties and go on with manipulations to obtain interesting informations.

Comment: I totally understand this. I just feel like a student should be given something more than a plain definition In fact, I could read that construction by myself, a teacher does not add or take anything to it, if he doesn't care about motivation, purpose, examples, etc. The analogy with cartesian product still works. How long would have taken to you to understand it via its universal definition? I guess s lot more, unless your mind is extremely fit for maths...